# In python, is it possible to plot colour map by giving coordinates and function value?

Tags: python, 2d, colormap, color-mapping

On the web, the only solution I find to plot the values of a two-dimensional function is to have a file with the matrix A(nxm) of the function's values and use matplotlib imshow. This will produce a map, whose extent (dimension along axes) has to be known and explicitly indicated.
Now, my concern arises from the fact that I need to plot two maps on the same axis, but one is slanted with respect to the other. So to say, I have a large main rectangular map and a smaller one that is oblique and superimposed.

In the end, the question is: is it possible to plot 2d maps starting from a file that is written as x, y, f(x,y) rather than just using f(x,y) so the plotting tool knows exactly where to draw?

Comment: It is possible. You could browse the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery#mplot3d) and see if you find anything usable all the examples include the code used to create the plots. [3d Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-toolkits-mplot3d-py)

Comment: Or for colors: [Colormaps Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html#tutorials-colors) and [examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#color-examples)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but all the mentioned solutions need the definition of the "linspace" where the function has to be plotted, that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Usually in the examples, linspace is only used to create *fake* data so that the concept can be demonstrated. Data is data and you should be able to adapt the examples to your data if the examples are relevant which is unknown since you didn't provide a toy example or example data ([mre]). To answer your question - Yes it is `possible to plot 2d maps starting from a file that is written as x, y, f(x,y) rather than just using f(x,y) so the plotting tool knows exactly where to draw`.

Comment: I did not post a mwe since I did not have an issue plotting. I was looking for a tool different than imshow. I luckily found it in pcolormesh that can draw a map given the coordinates of each point and its "colour"-value.

Answer (score 0):

I luckily found what I was looking for in pcolormesh that can draw a map given the coordinates of each point and its "colour"-value.